# Is "My Email to Salesforce" static?

Tags: email, emailtosalesforce

not a complicated question but I can't find the answer. Does the email address found in Settings -> Email -> My Email to Salesforce ever change? Or can I add that email to a contact and just keep using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Mail to Salesforce gives you an email address that you can BCC in your emails. When you BCC this email address, it will try to relate the email to an existing lead, contact, opportunity, and other records based on your configuration. The email address never changes in that environment.

I recommend reading here for more information:

- [Salesforce Help: How Does Email to Salesforce Work?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_my_email_2_sfdc.htm)